ERROR creating bean for org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate
Stack Trace: Sorry I have to scrub this for policy reasons.
Using Eclipse
Maven Build
orgspringframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate v6.1.10
On Compile in Eclipse StackTrace
INFO: Stopping service [Tomcat]
Timestamp [main] Error org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication - Application run failed org.springframework.beans.factory.UnstisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'Class object': Unsatisfied dependency express through field 'customeName'
    \\ Note the Class in question does have 
    @Component annotation 
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("customName")

: No qualifing bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate' available: exprected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate.  Dependency annotation: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true), @org.springframework.bean.factory.annotation.Qualifier("customName")}
Plus
--- Omitted
@SpringBootApplication( exclude = ???? // Violating Company Policy
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"packageName"})

public class ClassName {
   public stack final String App_ID = "String";

   @Genrated
   public static void main(final String[] args) {
        Log.info("Application initializing")
        SpringApplication.run(ClassName.class, args);
        Log.info("Application initialized"
   }
}

Later down the trace
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: no qualifying bean of type 'org.springframework.jms.core.JmsTemplate'
Believe me I see the Maven Dependency for JmsTemplate in Package Explorer in Eclipse.

Edited by OP moojjoo - 20241029 10:29:00
In a different class
@Component
public class MyClass extends Base{

@Autowired
@Qualifier("customName")
private JmsTeamplate jmsTemplate;

// Rest of code omitted

And this component resides in the componant scan -
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"packageName"})
Thoughts from Moojjoo, this project I am working on I have been told it does not matter if the Module compiles as long as the Unit tests pass then perform Git > Stage > Commit > Build in Jenkins and work from the errors in Jenkins Build.  The strange part these issues in the development environment are not happening as in my local and I have all the development settings in my application-local.properties and running as that profile


Just having the dependency is not enough.  Where do you define the JmsTemplate bean?

@lane.maxwell, see edit to question above.  My workplace does not allow copy/paste or comments.

Ok, I see where you are trying to use it, but don't see any code where you are creating it.  You need to create a Bean that is of type JmsTemplate, are you doing this?  Also, if you only have one JmsTemplate bean, you don't need to qualify it.

To all who assisted, I actually was told to only focus on Jira Stories and Unit Test / Coverage.  For some reason when this gets added to CICD it builds fine.  Thank you everyone for your help.
